# How to handle solved problems (answer the own question?)

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[This question contains the (possible) solution as edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25228/avoid-pause-during-dm-raid-initialization)

Some of you had the opinion that I should have answered my own question instead of doing an edit of the question.

Pro (putting the solution as edit):

- I wanted to document my findings as well as a solution just below the original question (like I put important facts on top of any wiki article).
- There was an accepted answer that lead to the described solution
- Answering my own question is like talking to myself (which is the first sign of mental problems)

I would like to hear/discuss your arguments here why I should have answered my own question instead.

Comment: Same question on Photo-SE meta, for what it's worth: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted

Comment: And Photo-SE has the same conclusion: a) don't do it; b) if you see someone edit the post to add an answer, reverting it is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I wanted to document my findings as well as a solution just below the original question (like I put important facts on top of any wiki article).

Having the answer right under the question is great; that's why the site already supports it. It sorts (by default) the answers so the accepted answer is first, followed by the top voted answers

> There was an accepted answer that lead to the decribed solution

Awesome -- upvote it. However, either it solved your problem or it didn't; if it wasn't the complete solution then just post your own

> Answering my own question is like taling to myselv (which is the first sign of mental problems)

It's actually like talking to other people that have the same problem and stumble across your question. There are [quite a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) posts on the main meta site about answering your own questions. I think it's universally accepted; there's even [a badge for it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/badges/13/self-learner). The whole site is structured around questions and answers -- posting answers in the question field when there's already an answer field is nonsensical

Comment: You convinced me. But in this case - the solution is still open, so I do have to edit that question accordingly.