# Should faq include not including solution in question

Tags: discussion

We've come against a newbie that insists that he edit his question with the solution.  When someone reverted the question to the original, he objected.

This question is a followup to [How to handle solved problems (answer the own question?)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/809/how-to-handle-solved-problems-answer-the-own-question)  I read the FAQ and noticed that it does not mention the convention that the question is not edited with the solution, but that you mark the answer which best answers the question.

Should the FAQ be updated to note this convention?  Newbies won't immediately know to look in meta for this convention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the comments in the [Photo-SE question on the same topic](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/should-edits-which-add-the-accepted-answer-to-the-question-be-reverted) are appropriate. Editing the "top post" to have the answer is common courtesy on bb-style forums.

*That is because BB-style forums suck.*

This is not a BB forum. This is a QA site with custom-designed software designed specifically to fix the problem that editing questions in a BB site with "[SOLVED!]" is a horrible kludge for. So, by editing answers into the question, one is a) not taking advantage of that, and b) making a cluttered mess that makes things worse.

So, yeah, I'm in favor of putting it in the FAQ more strongly.

Comment: I completely agree with your post, and that "*BB-style forums suck*", so don't take it the wrong way when I say "*custom-designed software designed specifically*" is one of the more amusing redundancies I've seen today.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of does, in [How do I ask questions here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask):

> When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.
>
> http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png
>
> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question.

It doesn't specifically say "don't edit the answer into your question", but I would think it's assumed based on how answers work. We can look into adding it if it happens a lot, but I think it's fairly rare

Comment: The argument that I'm making is that newbies won't make this assumption.  This wasn't the first time I've seen it, but it's the first time that I've seen a newbie getting mad when a senior moderator tries to correct the question back to the original.

Comment: @Arcege I hope you did not see my comments as "going mad" - apart from that my specific question has been edited after I discussed this on meta.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am the "newbie"  who discussed this on meta - yes the FAQ seems to be the right place for this.